# Allowing credit card payment services inside iFrame apps

Tags: credit-card, facebook-credits

I'm wondering what the policy for providing credit card payments are inside of iFramed apps. I understand that this is against the rules and that Facebook asks for credits to be used, but there are examples out there of iFramed ecommerce sites using credit card payment, notably the Nike Australia Facebook site at:

https://www.facebook.com/nikesportswearau/app_203425663079923

Just wondering if this is allowed as I think this would be a great feature to include in other iFramed apps.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apps on Facebook.com are not required to use credits as their payment method unless they are a game, which are required to use credits.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know that you can actually use your credit card.. I will research a bit more into it tomorrow. I thought facebook credits is the only currency that you can use on facebook. Great find!